# how to set a limit in the result in php

Tags: php

I'd like to have 3 limits in issuing vaccine but I don't know how to do it.

Here's my code:

```
$checkPatients = $conn->query("Select date from `vaccine` where itr_no = $_GET[id] ORDER by date DESC  limit 1 ");
$fetchPatients = $checkPatients->fetch_array();
if(date('m/d/Y', strtotime($fetchPatients['date'])) != date('m/d/Y'))
{
    ?>
    <button class = "btn btn-primary" id = "show_com"><i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus">ADD</i></button>
    <br />
    <?php
}
else if(isset($_GET['result'])){
    if($_GET['result'] == 'success'){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="font-weight: bold;">Save Successfully</div>';
    }
}
else{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="font-weight: bold;">
    '.ucfirst($_GET['firstname'])." ".ucfirst($_GET['lastname']). ' was already given a vaccine today. Thank you!.</div>';
}
```

Right now, I can issue one vaccine, but after that I already get this alert:

> ```
> echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="font-weight: bold;">
>         '.ucfirst($_GET['firstname'])." ".ucfirst($_GET['lastname']). ' was already given a vaccine today. Thank you!.</div>'; `
> ```

What I want to happen is I have to give a max of 3 vaccines before receiving the said alert.

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: In your query, `COUNT` the number of rows that match today. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: it's not working :(